# onTouch event sometimes not firing ACTION_POINTER_DOWN

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement pinch-zoom in an app I'm making and am having issues with the onTouch event. It appears that the pointer up & down actions do not fire immediately, like you won't get a pointer up or down until an action move occurs. So what happens if both fingers hit the screen nearly simultaneously is that the 2nd finger (should be pointer(1)) gets a move action before pointer down is called, making the code think it's a DRAG not a pinch zoom. Anyone else seen this? Anyway around it? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

be sure to include MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK in your switch. For example:

```
switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
some code
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
ETC
```

Comment: WOW! This actually solved my problem! I can't figure out why... but hey! Thanks :D

Comment: You da real mvp @tayler!

Comment: you saved my day dear.. thnxx a lot !

Comment: You can use ready-made support method for that: `MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)`

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: The real question is why we have to mask it anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a problem with the Custom ROM I had flashed to my Evo. Thanks again to hara for their advice as that turned out to be another bug I had.

Answer (score 1):

faced the same issue
turned out that ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN was being fired in my app when i touched the second finger and after that ACTION_MOVE was fired
the getAction() method gives the event number which needs to be checked against this list

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project. If i touch the screen and my fingers are too close togheter the system doesn't realize a multitouch event. I think that is because when your fingers are too close togheter the system sees it as a single finger.

Maybe you can check this assumption using [getSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getSize%28int%29) method to estimate the area of the screen being pressed when you touch the screen with a single finger and when you touch the screen with two finger close togheter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that will come in handy I'm sure. But I'm not sure that's my problem as it occurs no matter where I touch the screen. Using the debugger I can see that the pointer up and down events seem to always be delayed, and occur after a move event (and the move event always just has a single pointer in that instance). I even tried the "Dotty" app and could see same behavior in it. Could it be a hardware issue? I have an Evo w/ custom ROM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue with this:

```
switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
      //your code
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this(MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) case being fired if **onTouch(event) method has returned as true** as given below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        //your code
       break ;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note:
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN only getting listened if onTouch() method has returned a boolean value as return **super.onTouchEvent(event);** so make sure as true to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

@taylers answer in **Kotlin**

```
when (event.actionMasked and event.action) {
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        Some code
        This is fired when first finger touches screen.
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {
        Some code
        This is fired when second finger touches the screen.
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
        Some code
        This is fired when first finger is lifted.
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
        Some code
        This is fired when second finger is lifted.
    }
}
```